# Proving that every open subspace is locally homeomorphic to the original space

Tags: general-topology

In an exercise I'm asked to prove the following statement:

> If $(X,\tau)$ is an open subspace of $(Y,\tau_1)$, prove that $(X,\tau)$ is locally homeomorphic to $(Y,\tau_1)$.

This is actually my first exercise dealing with local homeomorphisms so I still don't know much about how to approach problems involving this topic and much about the topic itself.

This is what I did:

---

We have that $(Y,\tau_1)$ is a topological space and $(X,\tau)$ a subspace, with $X \in \tau_1$.

Now, let $f:X \to Y$ be a function. So, what I'm trying to do is to show that indeed $f$ can be a local homeomorphism. I don't know if this is the standard approach to this type of problems but it is what came to my mind when reading the statement.

So, let $x \in X$ be a point and $U \in \tau$ be an open neighborhood of $x$. This is $x \in U$.

If $f$ is a local homeomorphism, then the restriction of $f$ to $U$ is a homeomorphism, so we want to show that: $f|_U:U \to f(U)$ with $f|_U(x)=f(x)$ can be a homeomorphism.

My question is the following: Can indeed $f|_U$ be a homeomorphism? Because for that we need this function to be a bijection, but this restriction of $f$ is only a bijection if $f$ is a bijection right? Or am I making some mistake here? Furthermore, $f$ being a bijection implies that $X \sim Y$, and that is not allays true for all subspaces of $Y$. Yet I am asked to prove it, so what mistake am I making?

Comment: The question is simply wrong.

Comment: What is your definition of being locally homeomorphic? I can think of two for which this is true, but the proof will depend on which you choose. Anyway, your argument does not really make sense, since you did not specify the $f$.

Comment: "Let X and Y be topological spaces. Then $f: X \to Y$ is a local homeomorphism if, for each $x \in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U)$ is opened in $Y$ and $f|_U:U \to f(U)$ is an homeomorphism" @tomasz

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: I know what a local homeomorphism is, I'm just not sure what it means to be locally homeomorphic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re making it harder than necessary. Let $h:X\to Y:x\mapsto x$. Let $x\in X$ be arbitrary. Then $X$ is an open nbhd of $x$ in $X$, and $h\upharpoonright X=h$ is a homeomorphism from $X$ to $h[X]=X$, which is open in $Y$.